# How to setup sharing between two laptops on a wifi network

Tags: windows, network-shares, file-sharing, windows-10

I have two laptops which are connected through our home WiFi.

What I am trying to do is set up Remote Desktop to access one laptop from another and vice versa. I am also trying to set up shared folders between each laptops. Both laptops are running Windows 10 and connected through optimum router.

What is the best way to do it?

I have set up shared folder in one of my laptop, hence having a network path: `\\mypc\Users\kyle1\Pictures`, but not sure how to access it from the other laptop.

When I access `\\mypc\Users\kyle1\Pictures` from my other laptop it asks for network password, how do I get that?

Comment: Just try with your shared system password.

Comment: How do I get that? Is it the Windows password on each laptop?

Comment: try this - https://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/

Answer (score 1):

Try with:
Username: .\kyle1
password: WhatEverPasswordIsUsedByUser"Kyle1"on"mypc"

remember to allow filesharing in the firewall on both machines. Both incoming and outgoing.

Comment: so `mypc` is the place where file sharing is enabled. and `mypc2` is where I am trying to access from. So when I try to access the `mypc` folder from `mypc2` I should use the `mypc` windows username/password?

Comment: When I created an account it is myemail@gmail.com on the Windows login screen. Should I use that and the password that goes with it?

Comment: Yes, the computer you try to access should have an account which has been granted access. I'd suggest that you create a local user for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I find it way easier to use Chrome's remote desktop app - just install chrome on each laptop and install the remote desktop app on each. As for file sharing, consider using Googledocs or Microsoft's OneDrive.

Comment: I just setup the allow file sharing and homegroup and I can access each network path folders from another laptop. Thanks for the alternatives.